# Vue Router hosting on apache2

Tags: apache, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am hosting my vuejs project on apache server.

1. init project
2. setup router
3. Build and hosted to apache server

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: Routes,
  // relative: true,
  mode: 'history'
});
```

This runs fine in local, but vue router breaks on server.
Example

If I run http://example.com and go to http://exmaple.com/sub
It works fine

but if I refresh the page It will throw 404 Error.

Error:
[image]

Comment: This will provide you detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually/36623117#36623117

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the [vue.js documentation page](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html):

> When using history mode, the URL will look "normal," e.g. http://oursite.com/user/id. Beautiful!
>
> Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access http://oursite.com/user/id directly in their browser. Now that's ugly.
>
> Not to worry: To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives in. Beautiful, again!

### Apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is there a way to automatically include .htaccess into npm run build result?
I created a new question about it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397542/in-vue-how-to-include-htaccess-to-production-using-npm-run-build

Comment: Where do i write this?

Comment: @Desmond `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me, because my SPA is in a subfolder.Write this inside the **.htaccess** file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectoryName
RewriteRule ^subdirectoryName/index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdirectoryName/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Website folder: **C:\xampp\htdocs\dist**

**.htaccess** file ubication: **C:\xampp\htdocs\dist\.htaccess**

Credits:
https://gist.github.com/Prezens/f99fd28124b5557eb16816229391afee

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put the relevant part of the link in your answer as they may get expired or be removed.

Comment: This saved the day for me. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Since Apache 2.2.16, mod_rewrite is no longer necessary for this. Simply use `FallbackResource` under the `<Directory>` or `<VirtualHost>` configuration.

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

This will serve index.html for all URLs that do not map to anything.

Comment: Thanks! Works great in my dev environment.

Answer (score 3):

Hi my friend if you are using Linux os, go this routes :
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`
And add the following code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond /var/www/html/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond /var/www/html/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This gives me a syntax error `RewriteCond: unknown flag 'L' `. Help plz.

Answer (score 1):

It seems its not your issue its `apache` **.htaccess** issue i guess,
your local may have that file and your server don't have it.

please once check it that, you also uploaded **.htaccess** to your server as its hidden file you may forgot to upload it.

if its not there you can check this reference help : https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

and add your own **.htaccess** file if its not there.