# In Vue, how to include .htaccess to production using npm run build?

Tags: .htaccess, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using Vue CLI 3 and vue-router mode history and had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879936/vue-router-hosting-on-apache2) problem.
Found out that after I run `npm run build`, I need to put `.htaccess` inside the dist folder.

How to make `npm run build` to automatically include the `.htaccess` so that I don't need to manually copy it into dist folder?

Comment: If you use webpack, you should check out this plugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

Comment: hi @MátéWiszt, thanks for the response. I don't know about webpack. I'll try your suggestion, but is it not possible to do this without plugin?

Comment: Sorry, I know only the usage of Vue with webpack, I never used it without it. But it came into my mind that if you put something into the static folder (still webpack with vuejs template), it will be automatically copied to the dist's static folder.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It might sound obvious, but placing the .htaccess inside the public folder seems to do the trick for me. Everything contained in public folder is copied as is to dist folder during build.

Comment: i don't have a public folder.  i am using webpack project

Comment: @MitchBroadhead I'm also using webpack from Vue CLI 3, and it has public folder which contains manifest.json, robots.txt, favicon, and index.html. Put the .htaccess there.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius yes i upgraded to vue cli 3 and that fixed it

Comment: I have public folder but .htaccess is not copied over in one project. It's copied over in another (Nuxt). Any ideas?

Comment: you may have static folder..put it inside that