# How to run Vue JS application on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-ec2

The `dummy_prototype_1` is a simple Vue JS application that is running fine on my local machine. Now, I uploaded my application to AWS EC2. I want to run this on a permanent URL `http://3.137.154.536:8000/`. However, the following code runs the server on localhost `http://localhost:8080/`. How can I run this on my permanent URL? Am I missing something? Let me know if any further information is required. I'm new to AWS, please, help me out.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-235:~$ ls
Codes
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-235:~$ cd Codes
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-235:~/Codes$ ls
dummy_backend_1  dummy_prototype_1  nodeserver_1
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-235:~/Codes$ cd dummy_prototype_1/
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-235:~/Codes/dummy_prototype_1$ npm run dev

> proto@1.0.0 dev /home/ubuntu/Codes/dummy_prototype_1
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /dist/
404s will fallback to /index.html
Unable to open browser. If you are running in a headless environment, please do not use the open flag.
{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }.
```

Here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "proto",
  "description": "Prototype",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Jason",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@melmacaluso/vue-modal": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase": "^7.14.2",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.15.1-sr.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vue-fusioncharts": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vuex": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: `webpack-dev-server` is meant for development. To place your app on a server just `npm run build` and copy the `dist/` output to your server. You're done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are planning for host a SPA on an EC2 instance, you'll need an HTTP server like **Apache**.

1. Follow [this guide](https://medium.com/@akshaypunekar/introduction-and-installation-of-apache-web-server-on-aws-ec2-instance-ad9027eab87f) to install apache on EC2
2. In your local system, build your vue project.

   ```sh
   npm run build
   ```
3. A `dist/` folder will be generated in the project root.
4. Upload the contents of `dist/` to `/var/www/html` on your EC2 instance.

**[Edit]** add history mode support config for apache.

For history mode you'll need to configure the server like this:

```xml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879936/vue-router-hosting-on-apache2).

**[Edit]** Upload dist to EC2 instance

From your project root, run the following command.

```sh
scp -i /path/to/ec2key.pem -r dist/ ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-235:/var/www/html
```

**[Edit]** Restart Apache2 server

```sh
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: [@Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone) updated the answer.

Comment: Try restarting the server

Comment: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I accidentally deleted my ```/var/www/html/index.html``` file. Now, after restarting the server, I'm getting the same output ```http://3.137.154.206/```. Is ```index.html``` is required? If yes, how do I restore it?

Comment: yes `index.html` is required. You can upload it again from your local dist folder.

Comment: After uploading index.js and restarting the server, the Vue js application is still not running. It is still showing "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page".