# Removing hashbang (#) on url when deployed on server

Tags: apache, vue.js, vue-router

This is my first time deploying an app on apache server.

In my localhost, I accessed my pages without hashbang (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/dashboard`),
but when I access it with my domain like `https://myapp.com/dashboard`, it says:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

but when I add `#/` before the dashboard it works.

I already set the `mode` to `history` in my VueRouter

any idea?

**EDITED** based on @Estust Flask's comment below

 I couldn't find the **httpd.conf** file so what I did was append the block below directly into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

however I cannot restart apache anymore, error.

Comment: The server needs to be configured for SPA to serve index page on every url except static assets. The question doesn't concern client side at this point.

Comment: oh i see, but can you give me a hint on how to do it tho? it'd be great. TIA.

Comment: Duplicate of [Vue Router hosting on apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879936/vue-router-hosting-on-apache2)

Comment: @EstusFlask I got some edit man. I hope you bear with me.

Comment: *however I cannot restart apache anymore, error* - what error? I don't deal with Apache. The syntax looks valid and mod_rewrite check guarantees that it won't fail because the module is missing. Providing enough info will seriously improve chances to get help on SO.